# Using db2look to mimic a database?

Tags: db2, db2-luw, db2-10.5

I'm in the process of migrating some databases from iso8859-1 to utf-8. One of the databases contain 1000+ tables, loads of procedures, functions, triggers, constraints etc. I would like to automate the process as much as possible since this is going to happen several times, and for several instances of the system. Ideally I would like to hand over the work to my friends Jenkins and Ansible ;-)

My plan was to generate the ddl with db2look, but it fails to generate the "objects" in correct order. I tried running both with and without the -ct flag (fails for different reasons). For example:

```
connect to <db>;
create table t1 (x int not null);
create unique index t1pk on t1 (x);
alter table t1 add constraint t1pk primary key (x);
connect reset;
```

running

```
db2look -d <db> -e -td @ -ct
```

generates the wrong order for the index and the constraint.

```
CREATE TABLE "DB2INST1"."T1"  (
              "X" INTEGER NOT NULL )   
             IN "USERSPACE1"  
             ORGANIZE BY ROW@ 

ALTER TABLE "DB2INST1"."T1" 
    ADD CONSTRAINT "T1PK" PRIMARY KEY
            ("X")@



CREATE UNIQUE INDEX "DB2INST1"."T1PK" ON "DB2INST1"."T1" 
            ("X" ASC)
            COMPRESS NO 
            INCLUDE NULL KEYS ALLOW REVERSE SCANS@
```

Removing -ct works in this trivial example, but fails in the actual database due to other dependencies.

I imagine migrating to UTF-8 is a quite common task so I'm curios on what people have done. The two possible solutions I see is to:

```
a) write a parser that inspects the catalog for database
   objects and sort them topologically using dependency tables.

b) write a parser that reads the output from db2look, identify
   each object and sort them topologically using dependency tables.
```

Clearly there are drawbacks with both of these, am I overlooking some trivial way to migrate the databases?

EDIT: An additional observation is that as long as an index does not contain any extra attributes compared to the implicitly created index through a unique / primary key constraint a `QL0605W` warning is raised. If on the other hand additional attributes are specified a `SQL0601N` error is raised. Example:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX X1 ON T1 (C1, C2) 
COMPRESS NO 
INCLUDE NULL KEYS 
DISALLOW REVERSE SCANS
```

generates a warning `SQL0605W` if a similar index is created via primary key statement.

On the other hand an index like:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX X2 ON T2 (C1, C2) 
INCLUDE (C3) 
CLUSTER 
COMPRESS NO 
INCLUDE NULL KEYS 
ALLOW REVERSE SCANS
```

generates an error `SQL0601N`. I assume this is due to the INCLUDE clause, but perhaps the CLUSTER clause will cause this behavior as well.

Comment: I often use db2look -d -a -l -e -o -td “@" that has worked for me.

Comment: Thanks, but that outputs objects in the wrong order for the db in question. I suspect that some of the problem is due to the db being created 2005 and that it had regular schema changes ever since.

Comment: Does setting the `AUTO_REVAL` database configuration parameter to `DEFERRED_FORCE` solve your problem?

Comment: @Ian, not really. That only helps for some dependency violations. I actually prefer running in an all or nothing fashion ( `db2 +c -s ...` ) so that I can safely say that everything is recreated correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rough idea on how to get database objects in the correct order. The dependency graph is not complete but seems to fulfil my needs.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import ibm_db
import ibm_db_dbi
from toposort import toposort, toposort_flatten

cfg = ...
conn = ibm_db.connect("DATABASE=%s;HOSTNAME=%s;PORT=50000;PROTOCOL=TCPIP;UID=%s; PWD=%s" % cfg,"","")

find_edges = """
select * from (
    SELECT 'CONSTRAINT' as type, CONSTNAME, TABSCHEMA, TABNAME, BTYPE, 'N/A', BSCHEMA, BNAME 
    FROM SYSCAT.CONSTDEP 
    WHERE TABSCHEMA NOT LIKE 'SYS%' AND BSCHEMA NOT LIKE 'SYS%'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'I', 'N/A', D.INDSCHEMA, D.INDNAME, D.BTYPE, 'N/A', D.BSCHEMA, D.BNAME 
    FROM SYSCAT.INDEXDEP D
    JOIN SYSCAT.INDEXES I
        ON D.INDSCHEMA = I.INDSCHEMA AND D.INDNAME = I.INDNAME 
    WHERE I.TABSCHEMA NOT LIKE 'SYS%'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'I', 'N/A', I.INDSCHEMA, I.INDNAME, 'T', 'N/A', I.TABSCHEMA, I.TABNAME
    FROM SYSCAT.INDEXES I
    WHERE I.TABSCHEMA NOT LIKE 'SYS%'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'F', 'N/A', R1.ROUTINESCHEMA, R1.ROUTINENAME, D.BTYPE, 'N/A'
         , COALESCE(R2.ROUTINESCHEMA, D.BSCHEMA), COALESCE(R2.ROUTINENAME, D.BNAME) 
    FROM SYSCAT.ROUTINEDEP D
    JOIN SYSCAT.ROUTINES R1
        ON D.ROUTINESCHEMA = R1.ROUTINESCHEMA AND D.SPECIFICNAME = R1.SPECIFICNAME 
    LEFT JOIN SYSCAT.ROUTINES R2 
        ON D.BSCHEMA = R2.ROUTINESCHEMA AND D.BNAME = R2.SPECIFICNAME AND D.BTYPE = 'F' 
    WHERE D.ROUTINESCHEMA NOT LIKE 'SYS%' AND D.BSCHEMA NOT LIKE 'SYS%' AND D.BTYPE <> 'K'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'T', 'N/A', TABSCHEMA, TABNAME, BTYPE, 'N/A', BSCHEMA, BNAME 
    FROM SYSCAT.TABDEP
    WHERE TABSCHEMA NOT LIKE 'SYS%' AND BSCHEMA NOT LIKE 'SYS%'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'X', 'N/A', TRIGSCHEMA, TRIGNAME, BTYPE, 'N/A', BSCHEMA, BNAME 
    FROM SYSCAT.TRIGDEP
    WHERE TRIGSCHEMA NOT LIKE 'SYS%' AND BSCHEMA NOT LIKE 'SYS%'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'T', 'N/A', TABSCHEMA, TABNAME, 'T', 'N/A', REFTABSCHEMA, REFTABNAME
    FROM SYSCAT.REFERENCES
    WHERE TABSCHEMA NOT LIKE 'SYS%'
    ORDER BY 3,4
)
"""

sedges = ibm_db.prepare(conn, find_edges)
edges = {}
ibm_db.execute(sedges, ())
lastnode = None
tpl = ibm_db.fetch_tuple(sedges)
while tpl:
    n1 = (tpl[0], tpl[1], tpl[2], tpl[3])
    n2 = (tpl[4], tpl[5], tpl[6], tpl[7])
    if lastnode == n1:
        edges[n1].add(n2)
    else:
        # print("new")
        edges[n1] = set()
        edges[n1].add(n2)
        lastnode = n1
    tpl = ibm_db.fetch_tuple(sedges)

x = list(toposort_flatten(edges))
```

Now, x can be used to pick things in the correct order from db2look. I used a trivial parser that reads the output from `db2look` into lists. By looping over x and picking the definition from the right bucket, a sorted output can be achieved. The parser itself is just a bunch of regular expressions and not particularly interesting, but since the statements are spread over several lines, a stmt reader is nice to have:

```
 # helper for reading stmt by stmt
def myreadlines(f, newline):
    buf = ""
    while True:
        while newline in buf:
            pos = buf.index(newline)
            yield buf[:pos]
            buf = buf[pos + len(newline):]
        chunk = f.read(4096)
        if not chunk:
            yield buf
            break
        buf += chunk
```

EDIT: I have a parser up at https://github.com/lelle1234/Db2Utils. It is by no means complete but worked for my needs.

There is also an index advisor there which tries to come up with an optimal set of indexes for a given query and a database.

Answer (score 1):

Few years ago we migrated our DB2 from 9.7 to 10.5. We also moved the database to new hardware and implemented data compression. Because of this we decided to create the database from scratch and export and import the data.

We used db2look and db2move to do the job. However, there was no way to get the DDL created by db2look in the correct order. We had to split the generated script into different parts for creating tables, creating triggers, creating indexes, etc.

Finally we end up with the following steps:

- export the existing data
- create the new database
- create bufferpools and tablespaces
- create tables
- create primary keys
- create indexes
- create views
- load data
- run reorgs and runstats
- create stored procedures, user defined functions and triggers

I hope it helps, even it is not the answer you may have expected.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. The situation is a bit more complicated (there are for example tables that are dependent of functions and vice versa). I'll probably create a parser that sort the output from db2look in topological order using dependency tables.

Answer (score 0):

I have used following approach to copy production schema to test servers for developers. Trick is  to ignore errors during individual runs and compare schema at the end to make sure everything is recreated correctly. I know it is not a clean approach. I have done this against schema with over 1000 tables, 500 functions with dependencies, constraints, etc.. You can automate the steps using shell script. It  requires lot less effort compared to writing parser and testing it.

Step 1 Use script to extract schema from production server in specific order (db2look for tablespaces first, db2look for tables next, etc..). Using specific order reduces number of iterations for step 2 & 3.

Step 2 Run output from step 1  on test server

Step 3 Extract schema from test server and compare it with schema from production server

Step 4 Repeat step 2 and 3, until both schema are in synch.